# Search User Input for Specific Words

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will search for a specific word(s)  in a users input. For example the user enters an essay and it scans for every time it says “and” and it will flag/ notify the user where it says “and”
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a minimal reproducible example, which can be tested by others

Comment: More advice: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of a substring in another string using regex. Here is an example:

```
import re

s = input("Input text: ")
pattern_input = input("Word to search: ")

pattern = r"%s" % pattern_input
appearances = [(elem.start(0), elem.end(0)) for elem in re.finditer(pattern, s)]
print(appearances) # Index of start and end of your searched words
```

You can read more about regex and the finditer() function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer). In the future please try to provide a code sample of what you have already worked on, this way you learn more from it and we can give better answers.

**Example Input:**
Input text: hello and goodbye and hello
Word to search: and

**Example Output:**
[(6, 9), (18, 21)]